# How to set TimeOut for OwinContext in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

When a user access a website and enters their credentials which are stored in our database, we when create an authentication.

How do you set the timeout?
Using MVC 5.

My Authentication looks like this:

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", user.UserID.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserID.ToString()));
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The way to set an fixed expiration time span is to set the `ExpireTimeSpan` property in your `Startup.Auth.cs` file like this:

```
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2)
});
```

Note that you'll also have to set the cookie to persist. In your code you'll have to pass in a bool in addition to the username and password, and then change

```
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

to be

```
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = rememberMe }, id);
```

Comment: Worked but just a correction:    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, id);

Comment: Glad to hear. Be sure to mark the question as answered.

Comment: unfrortunately this is not working for me, any other alternative?

Answer (score 4):

With the following you do not need to use Startup.cs

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), }, id);
```

Comment: This helps me because my TimeOut is different for different users.