# User is logged off before timeout at web farm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I use `OWIN` for `Form-authentication` for Single Page Application application developed using ASP.NET Web API and AngluarJS 1.5.8.
We have a load balancer and web farm which consists of 4 servers.

The problem is that user is logged off by ASP.NET **before** `timeout`(30 minutes) automatically. I mean `aspxauth` expires before 30 minutes.

I've read that this is necessary to have the same `machineKey`  at all nodes of web farm to prevent logoff. And I've created the same machine key, but problem of logoff still exists.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" 
         protection="All" />
  </authentication>

  <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <sessionState mode="Off" />
  <machineKey decryption="AES"  
      decryptionKey="123GHJKYUILM"                 
      validationKey="0FDFFGFG456HGGHCFKL" />     
</system.web>
```

What can be a reason of expiring `aspxcookie` before `timeout`(30 minutes)? I mean users become logged off.

Comment: OWIN authentication has its own configuration which is configured in the Startup.Auth.cs class, the normal <forms> configuration is related to the old membership authentication, check your own startup file and see what is the time there, check this answer to know how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944783/how-to-set-timeout-for-owincontext-in-mvc-5

Comment: @HaithamShaddad so do not I need any conditions of `OWIN` in `web.config`?

Comment: OWIN doesn't depend on web.config, so yes, no need for web.config